# MySQL LIKE keyword not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a stored procedure that I used with a search function I created. The query within the procedure is as follows:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `advanced_search`(IN major_name VARCHAR(45), 
OUT major_code INT, IN classification VARCHAR(45), IN job_class VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
SELECT major_id INTO major_code FROM major 
WHERE major = major_name;

SET @classification = classification;
SELECT * FROM job WHERE (major = major_code) OR (classification LIKE '%@classification%') OR (job_type = job_class);
END
```

I am having a problem with LIKE keyword clause. I want to check if a value in the classification field contains or includes the @classification variable. For some reason when I single out the clause that uses that keyword (by removing the first and third clause in the WHERE statement) it does not return anything.

Is there any advice on how to fix this?

Also, is it common for the object that appears below to be found within the results object?

```
    {
  "fieldCount": 0,
  "affectedRows": 0,
  "insertId": 0,
  "serverStatus": 34,
  "warningCount": 0,
  "message": "",
  "protocol41": true,
  "changedRows": 0
}
```

EDIT: Here is the query I call

```
set @major_name = 'Chemical Engineering';
set @major_code = 0;
set @classification = 'Freshman';
set @job_class = 'Assistant';
call aggie_soop.advanced_search(@major_name, @major_code, @classification, @job_class);
```

[image: Search Results after running procedure]

These are the results. This is the exact same as the original table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a user-defined variable, you can reference the procedure argument.

You can use the MySQL CONCAT() function to concatenate the percent sign literals with the value.

I prefer to *qualify* all column references, and use a naming convention for procedure variables that avoids name collisions. While MySQL doesn't care, it makes it much easier for the future reader to decipher the intent.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `advanced_search`
( IN  p_major_name     VARCHAR(45)
, OUT p_major_code     INT
, IN  p_classification VARCHAR(45)
, IN  p_job_clas       VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT m.major_id INTO p_major_code
    FROM major m
   WHERE m.major = p_major_name
   LIMIT 1
  ;
  SELECT j.*
    FROM job j
   WHERE (j.major = p_major_code)
      OR (j.classification LIKE CONCAT('%',p_classification,'%')
      OR (j.job_type = p_job_class)
  ;
END
```

(I believe it's possible to "read" the value of the OUT parameter within the procedure, but I've never done it before.)

Note that if the p_classification string is a zero length string, then every row with a non-NULL value in the classification column is going to be returned.

You may want something like this:

```
      OR (p_classification <> '' AND j.classification LIKE CONCAT('%',p_classification,'%')
```

(But the specification isn't clear.)

Comment: Thank you for your response! After trying your solution I get the same result as Walter's

Comment: The query in this answer uses a string concatenation function CONCAT().  operation. The query in Walter's answer uses a logical OR operator. In some cases, the results from the queries may be the same, but it's easy to demonstrate cases where the queries will return different results. (As I noted in my answer, if the "p_classifcation" parameter is the empty string, the query will return *all* rows in the table that have a non-NULL value in classification column.

Answer (score 0):

A small change is needed:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `advanced_search`(IN major_name VARCHAR(45), 
OUT major_code INT, IN classification VARCHAR(45), IN job_class VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
SELECT major_id INTO major_code FROM major 
WHERE major = major_name;

SET @classification = classification;
SELECT * FROM job WHERE (major = major_code) OR (classification LIKE '%' || @classification || '%') OR (job_type = job_class);
END
```

Comment: Thank you for some reason I get an error saying that I am missing closing parenthesis around the % signs. I am editing the query in MySQL workbench

Comment: Just fixed the concatenation operators.

Comment: ok added the edit and now it gives me everything in the table even when the classification variable is not in the column

Comment: Well, this happens because the OR conditions in your query. You are basically saying to bring any rows where (major = major_code) OR (classification LIKE '%' || @classification || '%') OR (job_type = job_class). So, if any of the conditions are TRUE, the row is selected. This may bring more rows than the ones with a certain classification.

Comment: Maybe if you post an example of source data and result expected, we can tune your query. But one thing is certain: the query you have written seems to be working properly. So, it seems that you are not asking the database the right way.